# Pandas using loc for assignment in a Multi Index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, indexing

I have initialised a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["stockname","timestamp","price","volume"])
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
df.set_index(['stockname', 'timestamp'], inplace = True)
```

Now I get stream of data from somewhere but for the sake of program let me write it like this:

```
filehandle = open("datasource")

for line in filehandle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    data = line.split(",")
    stockname = data[4]
    price = float(data[3])
    timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data[0], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
    volume = int(data[6])

    df.loc[stockname, timestamp] = [price, volume]

filehandle.close()

print df
```

but this is giving error:

> ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

Comment: Can you add a sample of `"datasource"` ?

Comment: You know, you dont have to do all the heavy work of striping, spliting, just use `pd.read_csv`. If you add the sample of text file I would show you how to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify the column names you are assigning data to i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c","d"])
df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace = True)

df.loc[('3','4'),['c','d']] = [4,5]

df.loc[('4','4'),['c','d']] = [3,1]

      c    d
a b          
3 4  4.0  5.0
4 4  3.0  1.0
```

Also if you have a comma separated file then you can use `read_csv` i.e :

```
import io
import pandas as pd
st = '''2017-12-08 15:29:58:740657,245.0,426001,248.65,APPL,190342,2075673,249.35,244.2
        2017-12-08 16:29:58:740657,245.0,426001,248.65,GOOGL,190342,2075673,249.35,244.2
        2017-12-08 18:29:58:740657,245.0,426001,248.65,GOOGL,190342,2075673,249.35,244.2
        '''
#instead of `io`, add the source name
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(st),header=None)
# Now set the index and select what you want 
df.set_index([0,4])[[1,7]]

                                   1       7
 0                          4                   
2017-12-08 15:29:58.740657 APPL   245.0  249.35
2017-12-08 16:29:58.740657 GOOGL  245.0  249.35
2017-12-08 18:29:58.740657 GOOGL  245.0  249.35
```

Comment: this worked. Now you see I have stockname and timeframe. I want to access all data of a particular stock but I cannot write df[df.index == "XYZ"] so how do I write to access a particular stock data from dataframe ?

Comment: @Tahseen I need to see how the data actually looks like

Comment: 2017-12-08 15:29:58:740657,245.0,426001,248.65,APPL,190342,2075673,249.35,244.2

Comment: this one line of log and there would be many with same or different time stamp and same or different stockname. So in a single file, I am storing, multiple stocks tick prices at any particular time. That is why I indexed time and stockname

Comment: Guess what, its a one line of code of you use `pd.read_csv`, You can then rename the columns if you want, set the index as you like

Comment: See, data is not coming from csv. That I wrote just for the sake of showing. Data is coming as stream of json

Comment: There are plenty of built-ins. If you have `,` separated file then it need not to be csv it can be any file, pandas will take care of it. If you have json then you can use `read_json`

Comment: But this has worked perfectly file for me the way you did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `df.at[index, column_name] = value` to escape this error

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
df.loc[a,b,:] = [c,d]
```

Here is an example with your dataframe:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        df.loc[(str(i),str(j)),:] = [i,j]
```

Output:

```
     c  d
a b      
0 0  0  0
  1  0  1
  2  0  2
1 0  1  0
  1  1  1
  2  1  2
2 0  2  0
  1  2  1
  2  2  2
```